# Criando link em parte de tabela com divs

Tags: html5, css3

```css
.table{
  }
  .row-table-head, .row-table a{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 180px 70px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .row-table-head{
    display: block;
  }
  .row-table a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
  }
  .row-table a:hover .col-table{
    background-color: #d4ebff;
  }
  .row-table-head .col-table{
    padding: 2px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #eee;
  }
  .row-table .col-table{
   padding: 4px 6px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
```

```html
<body align="center">

      <h1>IMPEXPROS</h1>

      <div class="table">
        <div class="row-table-head">
          <div class="col-table">LISTA TODOS USUARIOS</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-table">
          <a href="http://www.google.com.br" target="_blank">
            <div class="col-table">9999</div>
            <div class="col-table">vitorpereira</div>
            <div class="col-table"><button type="button" name="excluir">excluir</button></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row-table">
          <a href="http://www.google.com.br" target="_blank">
            <div class="col-table">9999</div>
            <div class="col-table">vitorpereira</div>
            <div class="col-table"><button type="button" name="excluir">excluir</button></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row-table">
          <a href="http://www.google.com.br" target="_blank">
            <div class="col-table">9999</div>
            <div class="col-table">vitorpereira</div>
            <div class="col-table"><button type="button" name="excluir">excluir</button></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="row-table">
          <a href="http://www.google.com.br" target="_blank">
            <div class="col-table">9999</div>
            <div class="col-table">vitorpereira</div>
            <div class="col-table"><button type="button" name="excluir">excluir</button></div>
          </a>
        </div>


      </div>
</body>
```

Quando eu clico no botão excluir ele redireciona para o google. como tirar somente a parte do botão? eu coloquei o final da tag  antes da div do botão porém modifica o layout todo.

Comment: teu botão está dentro da tag **<a>**, então sempre que clicar ele redirecionará para o google, coloque ele fora da tag **<a href=""></a>**, não consegui entender o que deseja a mais.

Comment: quando eu coloco ele fora, o botão pula a linha e fica gigante

Comment: você está deixando ele dentro da <div>?

Comment: Sim, o teste que fiz foi colocar o final da tag </a> antes da div do button.

Comment: você colocou dessa forma **<div class="col-table"><button type="button" name="excluir">excluir</button></div>**, depois da tag </a>?

Comment: Exatamente dessa forma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

um forma será fazendo dessa maneira, colocando uma tag  para cada div, e criando uma classe "div-table" que ficar resposavel por gerar a tabela que antes era o que a tag  fazia, logo depois só estilizar as cores do :hover

CSS:

```
.table{
  }
  .row-table-head, .div-table, .row-table{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px 180px 70px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .row-table-head{
    display: block;
  }
  .row-table a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
  }
  .row-table a:hover .col-table{
    background-color: #d4ebff;
  }
  .row-table-head .col-table{
    padding: 2px 6px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #eee;
  }
  .row-table .col-table{
   padding: 4px 6px;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<body align="center">

      <h1>IMPEXPROS</h1>

      <div class="table">

        <div class="row-table-head">
          <div class="col-table">LISTA TODOS USUARIOS</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row-table">
          <div class="div-table">
            <a href="" class="col-table">
                <div>9999</div>
            </a>
            <a href="" class="col-table">
                <div>vitorpereira</div>
            </a>                
            <div class="col-table">
              <button type="button" name="excluir">excluir</button>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>

      </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Funcionou!! era isso mesmo que queria, obrigado Luan!